# push condition (i < data.length - 1) in array in es6

Tags: arrays, conditional-statements

i wanna push data of if condition into array in es6. Below is my code

```
  let i = 0;
  bankData.push({
  "flxLine": i < data.length - 1 ? {isVisible:true} : {isVisible:false},
  });
```

but it looks like my code just take first condition.
for the last row, output is not as expected

Comment: The code as presented doesn't make much sense to me. Here, `i` will always be 0, so `i < data.length -1` will always give the same result.

Comment: before push to array, the condition is  `for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i].flxLine = i  < data.length - 1 ? {isVisible: true} :{isVisible: false};
    } ` but when i wanna push to array, im quite confuse

Comment: Can you please include a complete example of what you're doing here? You're only confusing me further.

Comment: `i < data.length - 1` is looping another array data in order to check the last row. so, flxLine will be {isVisible:false} when met the last row of the data

Comment: what i wanna do is.. i wanna check for the last row of data, then the last row will set the visibility flxLine= true . These all later will push to bankData.

Comment: @mrukta I added answer, hope it will help you to understand the structure of JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the way to solve it.

```
for(let [i, bank] of data.entries()){
  bankData.push({
    "template": "flxBankSelectRow";
    "flxLine": i < data.length - 1 ? {isVisible: true} : {isVisible: false},
  });
}
```

My mistake is i didnt loop for index
.entries() would return the index.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- What is the significance of `i < data.length - 1` as i will always be `0`, so `i < data.length -1` will always give the same result.
- As per OP, you are pushing `{{isVisible:true}}` or `{{isVisible:false}}` in `bankData` array. which will be not a valid JSON.

**Invalid JSON :**

```
[{
    {}
}]
```

**Valid JSON :**

```
[{
    "key": {}
}]
```